# Работа с неинициализированной памятью

Tags: c++

Для того, чтобы получать неинициализированную область памяти, можно использовать и  `malloc` и `std::get_temporary_buffer`. Простой пример: чтобы не записать поверх, выделяю неинициализированную область для получения массива с алфавитом

```
constexpr size_t N = 26;
// вариант №1
char* pch = (char*)malloc(N + 1);
pch[N] = 0;
std::iota(pch, pch + N, 'a');
std::cout << pch << std::endl; 
free(pch);
```

То же самое можно сделать так:

```
//вариант 2
auto p = std::get_temporary_buffer<char>(N);
char* arr = p.first;
std::iota(arr, arr + p.second, 'a');
arr[p.second] = 0;
std::cout << arr;
std::return_temporary_buffer(arr);
```

Что может являться причиной того, чтобы прибегнуть ко второму варианту? P.S. Столкнулся с данной проблемой выбора при реализации  метода  `reserve` некого контейнера

Comment: get_temporary_buffer deprecated в С++17 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0174r0.html#3.3) поэтому малок

Comment: Вот спасибо, нуная инфа

Comment: студийная реализация get_temporary_buffer использует operator new возможно тоже будет полезно) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885849/difference-between-new-operator-and-operator-new

Comment: @goldstar_labs, конечно полезно, но  лично мне это было известно

Comment: Зачем использовать С-шный `malloc` и deprecated метод `get_temporary_buffer`? Для этого есть оператор `new` который кстати, даже может быть перегружен. Это лично мое мнение и мне кажется что оператор `new` увеличевает читабельность кода.

Comment: @ishidex,незачем, я просто привел пример. Мне нужно было понять что  такого особого в get_temporary_buffer и когда актуально ее использовать. new или  malloc ?... Это уже другой вопрос, который у меня не возникает